# Is there anything in Objective-C similar to C# yield return

Tags: objective-c

is there anything in Objective-C similar to C# `yield return`?

Comment: @Cœur Actually I would suggest duplicating the other way and have done so; even though this one is later, it contains great and classic answers, one of which is accepted, while the other goes nowhere.

Comment: @Cœur thank you for the pointer! good teamwork

Comment: In case someone is looking for the same question regarding Swift: [Swift equivalent of Ruby's “yield”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280896/swift-equivalent-of-rubys-yield)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing in Objective-C that would let you built an iterable solution that easily.

In general, [*fast enumeration*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) in Objective-C is built using an entirely different mechanism from C#, Java, or C++. Adopting the protocol is relatively complex, especially compared to C# with its `yield return`, though it is certainly doable.

I found that Objective-C blocks provide a usable alternative to fast enumeration. Consider implementing a block-based enumeration instead of fast enumeration - it lets you program your own API using the style similar to `yield return`. On the flip side, the clients of your API would need to supply a block to use your enumeration. This is not ideal, but usable, especially for complex enumerators, such as ones based on trees.

Comment: There is also a lot of added benefits from using a block instead of yield, because the callback can contain more then just the item being returned.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't directly and, as dasblinkenlight mentions, `fast enumeration` exists, but is quite a bit different.

Mike Ash took this question on in 2009 and came up with an implementation of generators (similar concept):

http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-10-30-generators-in-objective-c.html

Pretty neat bit of runtime wizardry, but I wouldn't necessarily suggest adopting it simply because it enables design patterns that are quite alien to the underlying system;  the maintenance and learning curve costs will be pretty steep for use in a production environment.