# Swift equivalent of Ruby's "yield"

Tags: ruby, swift

I'm new to Swift, and have a Ruby background. I'm wondering if there's a way I can do something like this:

```
def completion_handler response, &block
  yield response
end

extracted = proc {|r| puts r}

completion_handler "response", &extracted
response
=> nil
```

I'm having a little trouble searching as `yield` mostly brings up sequence generators and I don't think that's what I'm looking for right now. I mostly want to know if this is possible because there's times I like to be able to extract a block to a proc object. In Swift, a closure looks like a block to me. Is there a similar extraction to a proc object?

Comment: If you do describe what you want without using Ruby as example maybe I (and other Swift developers who don't know Ruby) can help you.

Comment: @appzYourLife yeah, i'm sorry, i tried several times to sketch out what i meant in swift but had trouble. i may try again later. :/

Comment: Let's note that if the yielded response is used to build an array, then in Swift we frequently use [`.compactMap {}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anysequence/2950960-compactmap) or [`.map {}`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anysequence/2885020-map) for that purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swift closures mostly closely resemble Ruby Lambdas. They are objects with a defined set of arguments which return to their calling scope (unlike non-object Ruby Blocks or Ruby Procs which do not check argument count and where a `return` can escape the calling scope).

As such there's no real `yield` equivalent. Swift functions which accept a closure argument call the closure explicitly with a parenthetical argument list.

Comment: mm, so essentially swift has `block.call` but not `yield`. makes sense

Comment: Right, it might help to think of it as a consequence of Swift's more explicit types. Since we must know the type signature of a Swift closure we can call it explicitly and there's no equivalent for `yield`ing with a very flexible set of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to save block (or 'closure' as in swift programming guide) in variables or pass them around. A big difference to ruby is that some types have to specified to compile.

Example code (only tested with swift 2.2-dev linux):

```
func foo(arg1: Int, block: ((Int)->(String))? = nil) {
    if let block = block {
        // ruby's yield (call the block with argument and get its return value)
        // is not part of swift grammar, so we have to call it manually.
        print(block(arg1))
    }
}

// named closure
let block1 = {(a: Int)->String in
    print("yielded", a)
    return "returned from block1"
}

foo(1, block: block1)

// unnamed closure
foo(2, block: {
    print("yielded", $0)
    return "returned from block2"
})

// unnamed closure in another syntax. usable only when the closure is the last argument.
foo(3) {
    print("yielded", $0)
    return "returned from block3"
}
```

Output:

```
yielded 1
returned from block1
yielded 2
returned from block2
yielded 3
returned from block3
```

Comment: thanks for these examples. one more i found helpful to consider was a named closure with an unnamed parameter:  `func handler(input: String, block: (String) -> ()) { block(input) }; let smallBlock = {print("yielded", $0 as String)}; handler("hi", block: smallBlock);` which returns `yielded hi`

Comment: instead of `if let block = block`, you can directly use `block?(arg1)`